# Why property value with 'this' not working in constructor object?

Tags: javascript

When I'm trying to create a new constructor object within another constructor function, I can't use `this.time` when I create the object. But I can use `this.time` in a method and return the value. How come it is like this?!

I only get `undefined` in return when I run the second console.log. It's about this line: `timeControl: new TimeControl(this.time)` If I use a value like `33` it works fine, but not with `this.time` Interested and curious why the code act like this?

(To minimize the code in this question, I'm not showing the `TimeControl` constructor)

```
    // Box
Box = function(x,y,value) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.time = value;
    // Create a new object of TimeControl
    //this.timeControl = new TimeControl(this.time); // OK to create object here!
}
Box.prototype = {
    // Create a new object of TimeControl
    timeControl: new TimeControl(this.time), // But not OK here! Works if I enter a number
    test1: function() {
        return this.time;
    },
    test2: function() {
        return this.timeControl.getTime();
    }
};

var box = new Box(10,10,14);
console.log("Duration: " + box.test1()); // Works fine
console.log("Duration: " + box.test2()); // Returns undefined if this.time is used
```

Comment: `this` has meaning inside of a function. There's no function there.

Comment: In the second case, `this` is not bound to any value. What value would you expect it to have? (If you expect to have a different `time` value for each instance of `Box`, then `timeControl` doesn't belong in the prototype.)

Comment: @TedHopp But don't 'this.time' get the value from the 'value' variable in the Box constructor?

Comment: I'd say this is a duplicate of the famous http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword. Asking about `this` requires an understanding of `this`.

Comment: No, because JavaScript needs to evaluate `this.time` when it is building the object to assign to the prototype.

Comment: Hmm, it's a little bit complicated to understand! ;) But why can I get the value with the call to the 'test1' method? Could it be done in another way? I have to leave and I will continue later with this question. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help you understand how you can and can't use prototype: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 0):

change  `timeControl` to a function then return new TimeControl from it because inside prototype `this` is holding the ref of `window` object .

```
TimeControl = function(time){
this.time=time;
    console.log('time control initialized time is ='+this.time);
}
TimeControl.prototype = {
    getTime:function(){
    return this.time;
    }
}
Box = function(x,y,value) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.time = value;
    // Create a new object of TimeControl
    //this.timeControl = new TimeControl(this.time); // OK to create object here!
}
Box.prototype = {
    xyz:this.time,//here this.time is undefined as this is holding ref of window object
     // Create a new object of TimeControl
    timeControl:function(){return  new TimeControl(this.time)}, // But not OK here! Works if I enter a number
    test1: function() {
        return this.time;
    },
    test2: function() {
        return this.timeControl().getTime();
    }
};

var box = new Box(10,10,14);
console.log("Duration: " + box.test1()); // Works fine
console.log("Duration: " + box.test2()); // Returns undefined
console.log("xyz: " + box.xyz);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/df6bgk8L/2/

Answer (score 0):

When you define function in object property like `timeControl: new TimeControl(this.time)`, this function immediately invokes. So `this` will be `window`. Solution for this - use anonymous function:

```
BoxPrototype: {
    timeControl: function() {
        return new TimeControl(this.time);
    }
}
```

Or init `TimeControl` in constructor function:

```
Box = function(x, y, value) {
    this.time = new TimeControl(value);
}

Box.prototype = {
    getTimeControl: function() {
        return this.time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand why "`this`" is not working, you have to understand how `this` and `scopes` work in javascript.
in javascript you have only two scopes, Global scope and Function scope.

When you create a object using new operator, you are essentially setting the context of the new object to `this`.so `this` will point at the new object.And also since functions have its own scope the first code works.

When you use the object literal(second snippet) for creating a object. the keyword `this` would point at the global object(depending on the context).since you don't have a property called `time` in the global object, this.time does not work.Object literals are javascript expression and they dont create a scope by themselves.the scope is decided based on where they are living.

i would modify the prototype object on these lines

```
Box.prototype = ({
  timeControl: null,
  test1: function() {
    return this.time;
  },
  test2: function() {
    return this.timeControl.getTime();
  },
  setTimeCtrl: function() {
    //set the timecontrol object here
    this.timeControl = new TimeControl(this.time);
    return this;// return the newly created object
  }
}).setTimeCtrl(); //invoke it as soon as you create the object
```

this makes sure the object is created and then necessary properties are set afterwards